# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: data is not a function?

Tags: javascript

Where is a mistake? Console says "**Uncaught TypeError: data is not a function**"

```
data = '';
x = 0;

$('._post .post .page_block .all .own').each(function(){

    if(x < 5){
       data += 'postid'+i+'='+$('.page_block', 
       this).text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'')+'&';
    }
    x++;

});
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that code you posted can cause that error.

Comment: @Pointy checked x20 time, problem caused by variable duplicating.

Comment: Where is i variable defined?